# Creating submenu in nav menu

Tags: html, css

I want to create submenu in my nav menu. i have little knowledge of css.
but facing some prob.
when i add submenu into nav menu. menu shows as ul li,direct ally.

```css
#cssmenu {
  background: #88BC18;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  zoom: 1;
}

#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#cssmenu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul li {
  float: right;
}

#cssmenu.align-center ul {
  text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: color .25s;
  -moz-transition: color .25s;
  -ms-transition: color 25s;
  -o-transition: color .25s;
  transition: color .25s;
}

#cssmenu ul li a:hover {
  color: #004900;
}

#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: #004900;
  -webkit-transition: width .25s;
  -moz-transition: width .25s;
  -ms-transition: width 25s;
  -o-transition: width .25s;
  transition: width .25s;
}

#cssmenu ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  top: 19px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: .5;
}

#cssmenu ul li.last>a:after,
#cssmenu ul li:last-child>a:after {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu ul li.active a {
  color: #004900;
}

#cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu.align-right li.last>a:after,
#cssmenu.align-right li:last-child>a:after {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu.align-right li:first-child a:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navWrap">
  <nav class="nav">
    <div id="cssmenu" class="centered">
      <ul>
        <li class='first'><a href="#welcome" class="smoothScroll"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio" class="smoothScroll"><span>Features</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#services" class="smoothScroll"><span>About</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#prices" class="smoothScroll"><span>Prices</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="faq.html" class="smoothScroll"><span>F.A.Q</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="how-to-uses.html" class="smoothScroll"><span>How to Use</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="smoothScroll"><span>Log In</span></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#" class="smoothScroll"><span>Help</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a tip: rather use classes for your CSS selectors, `id`s should be avoided where possible, they're over-kill when used as selectors mainly because of their specificity; they essentially over-qualify everything other than inline styles, or style rules using the `!important` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you get started. Added css for submenu.

Check the `About` Link now.

```css
#cssmenu {
  background: #88BC18;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  zoom: 1;
}

#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#cssmenu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul li {
  float: right;
}

#cssmenu.align-center ul {
  text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: color .25s;
  -moz-transition: color .25s;
  -ms-transition: color 25s;
  -o-transition: color .25s;
  transition: color .25s;
}

#cssmenu ul li a:hover {
  color: #004900;
}

#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: #004900;
  -webkit-transition: width .25s;
  -moz-transition: width .25s;
  -ms-transition: width 25s;
  -o-transition: width .25s;
  transition: width .25s;
}

#cssmenu ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  top: 19px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: .5;
}

#cssmenu ul li.last>a:after,
#cssmenu ul li:last-child>a:after {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu ul li.active a {
  color: #004900;
}

#cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
  width: 100%;
}


/* New CSS for Sub Menu */
#cssmenu ul li {
  position: relative;
}

#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #88BC18;
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="navWrap">
  <nav class="nav">
    <div id="cssmenu" class="centered">
      <ul>
        <li class='first'><a href="#welcome" class="smoothScroll"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio" class="smoothScroll"><span>Features</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#services" class="smoothScroll"><span>About</span></a>

          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#prices" class="smoothScroll"><span>Prices</span></a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added the second item in menu to add a submenu in it and added two selector on the bottom of css. [Here is the sample](https://jsfiddle.net/L5297xdz/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="navWrap">
    <nav class="nav">
        <div id="cssmenu" class="centered">
            <ul>
                <li class='first'><a href="#welcome" class="smoothScroll"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="smoothScroll has_child"><span>Have submenu</span></a>
                  <ul class="submenu">
                  <li><a href="#">submenu one</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">submenu two</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#services" class="smoothScroll"><span>About</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#prices" class="smoothScroll"><span>Prices</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="faq.html" class="smoothScroll"><span>F.A.Q</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="how-to-uses.html" class="smoothScroll"><span>How to Use</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="smoothScroll"><span>Log In</span></a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#" class="smoothScroll"><span>Help</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#cssmenu {background: #88BC18;width: auto;z-index: 1; position: relative;}
#cssmenu ul {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 1; display: block; zoom: 1; }
#cssmenu ul:after {content: " ";display: block;font-size: 0;height: 0; clear: both;visibility: hidden;}
#cssmenu ul li { display: inline-block;padding: 0;margin: 0;}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li {float: right;}
#cssmenu.align-center ul {text-align: center;}
#cssmenu ul li a {color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;display: block; padding: 15px 25px;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight: 700; text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 14px;position: relative;-webkit-transition: color .25s;-moz-transition: color .25s;-ms-transition: color 25s;-o-transition: color .25s;transition: color .25s;}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover {color: #004900;}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {width: 100%;}
#cssmenu ul li a:before {content: "";display: block;position: absolute; left: 0;bottom: 0; height: 3px;width: 0;background: #004900;-webkit-transition: width .25s;-moz-transition: width .25s;-ms-transition: width 25s; -o-transition: width .25s;transition: width .25s;}
#cssmenu ul li a:after {content: "";display: block;position: absolute; right: -3px; top: 19px;height: 6px; width: 6px;background: #ffffff;opacity: .5;}
#cssmenu ul li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:after {display: none;}
#cssmenu ul li.active a {color: #004900;}
#cssmenu ul li.active a:before {width: 100%;}
#cssmenu.align-right li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu.align-right li:last-child > a:after {display: block;}
#cssmenu.align-right li:first-child a:after {display: none;}
#cssmenu .submenu{
  display:none;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul{
  display:block;
  width:200px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 44px;
  background: #88BC18;
}
```